# Matching Inverse of String in Windows CLI

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, findstr

Can anyone show me a good example of how to match it.  Maybe I misread the documentation a bunch of times, but it does not even some close to how real tools like grep ought to work.  The output of the following command, `wmic /output:stdout csproduct get identifyingnumber` looks like so.

> IdentifyingNumber
>
> ABC1234

`wmic csproduct get identifyingnumber | findstr with parameters to remove column header | clip`

I am not sure what to do because I cannot find an exact example of what I am looking for my batch file since I need the serial enough.  Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: I like PowerShell, but I really need to know how to do this in batch (must be possible) for XP machines as well.  I am just surprised I could not figure this out. I mean, this *should* be simple!

Answer (score 2):

use powershell do the following

gwmi win32_ComputerSystemProduct | ft   IdentifyingNumber  -hidetableheaders

Comment: Thanks, but was looking for something backwards compatible with some crappy XP images where PS is not installed. I appreciate it though.

Comment: And I am a jerk.  I forgot I tagged it win7 and not just windows.  I changed that after the fact, but shame on me for not asking the question right!

Comment: if you happen to have 1 win7 workstation you could still use the remote method!